# How to remove the malware which hijacks the homepage of various browsers by hao.360.cn

Tags: malware, antimalware

This has been really getting my nerve.
My friend installed some freeware which, in turn, hijacked the homepage of various browsers. The latter include chrome, edge, internet explorer, etc.

Here is the basic information on system hardware and software .

```
Hardware: Dell XPS13 9360
OS: Microsoft Windows Pro 10.0.18363
Anti-virus installed: Kaspersky 20.0.14
Internet Explorer: v11 (came together with windows)
```

When the problem first occurred, the homepages of all the browsers were hijacked. I attempted and managed to fix the problem with chrome and edge by googling and trying. In the case of Chrome, I simply brutally removed all the newly added files, then remove the software and reinstall it. In the case of edge, the problem is solved by simply alter the software configuration.

In the case of ie, what happens is that the homepage will be overridden to

```
http://hao.360.cn/?src=lm&ls=n0aa523c69e
```

for every single time one starts the browser.

It indeed seems to be more complicated. From google, I found some thread that discussed the issue. It indicates that the malware hijacked some system dynamic library entries and one needs to restore those carefully. I only followed the most simple approaches, namely, verifying the ie shortcut, resetting the ie configurations, and looking to system register setup for "start page" "homepage" etc. The above approaches do not work.

Althoug Kaspersky did not issue any warning, some google pages point to install certain malware remover. However, some of these, such as SpyHunter, might be potentially a scam themselves. Therefore, I question is

Is there a trustworthy malware remover I should try?
or 
What should I do?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Without knowing the exact type of malware, it is difficult to give specific instructions. My general recommendation for malware infected systems is wiping and a fresh install. Otherwise you can't be sure that you completely removed the malware and what kind of background activity is still ongoing. Your system could be part of a botnet, spy on you, be open through a backdoor, etc. Re-installing from ground up is the safest way to go.

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not a malware removal site. You need specialised advice

Comment: A patient went to see a pathologist, asking for a solution for his searing pain in the chest. "Unfortunately, you should go and see an M. D.," the pathologist replied while handing him a pamphlet, "also, your problem has already been answered here," he added. The patient anxiously looked down only to find the title of the beautifully lanced brochure reads, "What should I do when I generally feel sick?"